# Comparison of the dipole moments of CHCl3 and CBrCl3

Tags: dipole

> Consider compounds $\ce{CHCl3}$ and $\ce{CBrCl3}$: Which compound has the larger dipole moment? Explain your choice.

Okay, so I've been trying to figure it out and I thought dipole moment had to do with electronegativity but now I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

Dipole moments *are* related to electronegativity.

Draw the structures of $\ce{CHCl3}$ and $\ce{CBrCl3}$; in both cases, carbon is the central atom connected to either H, Cl, and/or Br. Then consider the electronegativities of H, Cl, and Br as compared to C. How do they pull on electrons? Does one molecule lead to a more uneven pulling of electrons compared to the other?